How to auto indent a selected block in vscode as in emacs
I am an emacs user and for a number of reasons I now have to use vscode.
I managed quite easily with the help of extensions to find almost all of the emacs shortcuts, only one of those that is most important to me is still missing: the auto indentation of blocks.
Thanks to the vscode-emacs-tab extension I now have automatic indentation on a line, but I would like to extend this to blocks of C++, Fortran codes etc...
Here is what I have tried so far in the shortcuts config file:
{
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "editor.action.reindentselectedlines",
  "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus"
},
{
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "emacs-tab.reindentCurrentLine",
  "when": "!editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus"
}

Strangely, this only works for tex files but not for other file types. Do you have any idea?
Thanks in advance.
